# Unity Parse Cloud Function Call - ParseException InvalidCastException?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

So I'm calling a Parse Cloud Code function in Unity to get a list of subclassed ParseObjects. However whenever it runs it always faults and gives me an InvalidCastException for the error.

I have already tried the solution posted [here](https://parse.com/questions/unity-cloud-function-call/) so I have defined the type I want as the result, but it's still giving me the error...

Here is the relevant functionality in Unity C#:

```
// prepare the pre-queue list with needed filters
    IDictionary<string, object> fetchInfo = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "requestLimit", PHRASE_REQUEST_LIMIT }
    };

    var fetchTask = ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<IEnumerable<ParsePhrase>> ("FetchPhrases", fetchInfo);

    while (!fetchTask.IsCompleted) yield return null;

    if (fetchTask.IsFaulted || fetchTask.IsCanceled) 
    {
        using (IEnumerator<System.Exception> enumerator = fetchTask.Exception.InnerExceptions.GetEnumerator()) 
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext ()) 
            {
                ParseException exception = (ParseException)enumerator.Current;
                errorInfo = new ErrorInfo(ErrorType.ParseException, exception.Code);
            }
            else 
            {
                errorInfo = new ErrorInfo(ErrorType.ParseInternal);
            }
        }

        keeperState = KeeperState.Error;
        yield break;
    } 
    else
    {
        IEnumerable<ParsePhrase> result = fetchTask.Result;
        if(result != null)
        {
            string debugString = "query results: ";
            foreach(ParseObject parseObject in result)
            {
                debugString += parseObject.Get<string> ("correctMessage") + "|";
            }
            Debug.Log (debugString);
        }
        else
        {
            errorInfo = new ErrorInfo(ErrorType.ParseInternal);
            keeperState = KeeperState.Error;
            yield break;
        }
    }
```

Also here is the relevant Cloud Code function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("FetchPhrases", function(request, response) {
  var requestLimit = request.params.requestLimit;

  if(typeof(requestLimit) != 'number')
    response.error("FetchPhrases: Invalid params");

  var query = new Parse.Query("Phrase");
  query.limit(requestLimit);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      response.success(results);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error(error);
    }
  });
});
```

Please help!

Comment: "here" link is redirects to parse-platform can you share what you tried already ?